# Feed Me - syncing asset fields

Tags: plugin-feedme, assets-field

I'm migrating a Craft 2 site to Craft 3 via rebuild. I've copied the assets over to the new site and indexed the upload directory - that all went well.
However, after doing this and working on other parts of the site I discovered that in the Craft 2 site all the assets had a redactor field attached to them. Is there a way in Feedme to copy over this data when the assets don't have the same asset id?
Sean

Answer (score 1):

Of course shortly after posting this I got it working.

Created a feed and used the filename as the unique identifier and voila imported redactor content to images for 2000+ images.